# How To Use JavaScript To Copy Text From One Field To Another

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Often when creating a form on a web page, I need our customers to fill out a field such as a permanent address, as well as a present address. Instead of having our customers fill out the form twice,I can use JavaScript to copy the form's data from one field to another.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/9wwok2rm/

Comment: How to get value of text field and how to set value of text filed is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
  <script>
    function myFunction(){
      console.log(this);
      document.getElementById('permanentaddress').value = document.getElementById('address').value
    }
  </script>
<body>
  Address: <textarea id="address"></textarea><br />
  permanent address:<textarea id="permanentaddress" onfocusin="myFunction()"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#txt2").on("focus",function(){
   $("#txt3").val($("#txt1").val());
});

$("#txt2").on("input",function(){
   $("#txt3").val('');
   var res=$("#txt1").val()+' '+ $(this).val();
   $("#txt3").val(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" readonly />
```